# 'Using an intent to insert an event' only partially working with third party apps?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I got the following problem:

Based on the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html), the following code is the official way to create an "Add-Event-To-Calendar"-Intent. I copied it from the docs without changing a bit.

---

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                    .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com");
```

---

It works like a charm when the Intent is handled by Google's own calendar app. Surprisingly, however, third party calendars seem to accept BEGIN_TIME and END_TIME, but ignore fields like TITLE, DESCRIPTION and EVENT_LOCATION.

First I thought, this must be a bug in the third party calendar. But as soon as a second one showed the same behaviour, I got suspicious.

These are the two calendar apps.

- [DigiCal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digibites.calendar)
- [Cal - Calendar by Any.do](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo.cal)

Why would they register for handling the Intent, but ignore these crucial and well documented extra fields?

Would be great if somebody has an explanation :)

Comment: I contacted the support of DigiCal regarding this issue and got the following response.
---
Thanks for reporting it, it's on our todo list waiting for implementation.
---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem of 3rd party apps. They don't implement all fields.

Comment: Exactly that was my observation :) But why would they do that? They have already registered their apps for the proper intent, and they do support some of the fields. But why won't they support all of them!? It's unlikely that they just have "forgot" to support all fields.

Comment: Maybe they forgot or didn't updated app for long time. In past calendar api was private. You can't do nothing about that because everyone can create calendar app and whatever he wants.